# Windows Docker encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker

I'm fairly new to Docker and trying to build a Windows container, but running into this issue when I go to run it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(base) D:\src\WebIntelligence\bling\blingDemo\Models>docker run -p 4200:4200 -it blingcontainer.azurecr.io/sdbackendfy22h2:v2.8 /bin/bash
docker: Error response from daemon: container c8a7a0c947264b7d07afc5e6c44aa5a8022ff7d12729f3cdf1fba2e1ba2f293a encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF73B53AE77: (caller: 00007FF73B4EE4AB) Exception(2) tid(388) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000].
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM woailaosang/sdserver:v1.2
MAINTAINER MyName

COPY SDWebServer/ Users/Administrator/Downloads/Models/SDWebServer/
```

Build Command:

```
(base) D:\src\WebIntelligence\bling\blingDemo\Models>docker build -t blingcontainer.azurecr.io/sdbackendfy22h2:v2.8 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   6.26GB
Step 1/3 : FROM woailaosang/sdserver:v1.2
 ---> 4de20ecd31b8
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER MyName
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 59cc461e724f
Step 3/3 : COPY SDWebServer/ Users/Administrator/Downloads/Models/SDWebServer/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ab457109f43
Successfully built 1ab457109f43
Successfully tagged blingcontainer.azurecr.io/sdbackendfy22h2:v2.8
```

Answer (score 7):

So turns out I was supposed to run using `cmd.exe` instead of `/bin/bash`, because it's a Windows docker image on a Windows machine.

Comment: Full command: `winpty docker exec -t -i <GUID> cmd.exe`

Answer (score 2):

Ok in my case I was getting exactly same error running docker container on Windows 10
I had `CMD` in Dockerfile. However, when I added `ENTRYPOINT` just before it, my container ran successfully:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell.exe"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "prod-win"]
```

Comment: this worked for me! Also worked without specify .exe extension: ENTRYPOINT [ "powershell"]

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error like this most of the time you will get the exact error message in:

```
docker logs <container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cdm.exe` instead of `/bin/bash`.

`docker exec -t -i container_name cmd.exe`